# Was it common practice for men to kiss on the lips in 1920s USA?

Tags: united-states, cultural-history, 1920s

I recently watched a documentary about [Eugene Debs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_V._Debs), which included [film of his release from prison in 1921](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-VUql_PZvA).  I was surprised to see that many of the men present greeted him by kissing him on the lips.

Was this practice widespread at the time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_fraternal_kiss

Comment: @Denis, this should be an answer, no?

Comment: It would need some expanding to be something other than a link-only answer, but it's the most likely explanation IMO. The bit I'm unsure about is how prevalent the use of the socialist fraternal kiss was outside of Russia at the time, hence the mere comment. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than I am will bite the bullet with relevant sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say it was normal. Probably not "common". It would be normal under highly emotional personal conditions.

The 1927 film *Wings* included an on the mouth kiss between two male best friends (first same sex kiss in film) as one of the men was dying.

Comment: I'm literally the only person who has ever answered this question, and you're mad.